# Add up Checkbox Values and Write to Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form with some checkboxes and a Javascript snippet where the checkbox values get added up and written to a `<span>`. That works fine but I would really like it to write to an input text field instead of the `<span>`.

Here is the checkbox section of my form:

```
<section id="extra-features">
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="outside" class="sum" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"> Outside Wash</label>
</div><br/>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="aclean" class="sum" value="39" data-toggle="checkbox"> A - Clean: Wash Vacuum, Windows, Wheels/Tires, Wax</label>
</div><br/>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="bclean" class="sum" value="0" data-toggle="checkbox"> B - Clean: Same as A above <em>PLUS:</em> Shampoo Interior, Clean/Dress Interior Panels, Remove Bugs/Tar.</label>
</div><br/>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="cclean" class="sum" value="109" data-toggle="checkbox"> C - Clean: Same as B above <em>PLUS:</em> Compound Polish Exterior, Clean/Dress Moldings as Needed.    </label>
</div>
</section>
```

This is the `<span>` that the javascript is writing to currently:

```
<span id="payment-total" style="text-decoration:underline;">0</span>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
window.onload=function(){
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    total  = document.getElementById('payment-total');

 for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the loop. Use jQuery's change() instead of onchange. It has an implicit loop. Also using jQuery for checked inputs is more reliable than custom tailored JS. Here's a minimal working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateSum() {
      var total = 0;
      $(".sum:checked").each(function(i, n) {total += parseInt($(n).val());})
      $("#total").val(total);
    }
    // run the update on every checkbox change and on startup
    $("input.sum").change(updateSum);
    updateSum();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="extra-features">
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="outside" class="sum" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"> Outside Wash</label>
</div><br/>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="aclean" class="sum" value="39" data-toggle="checkbox"> A - Clean: Wash Vacuum, Windows, Wheels/Tires, Wax</label>
</div><br/>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="bclean" class="sum" value="0" data-toggle="checkbox"> B - Clean: Same as A above <em>PLUS:</em> Shampoo Interior, Clean/Dress Interior Panels, Remove Bugs/Tar.</label>
</div><br/>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="cclean" class="sum" value="109" data-toggle="checkbox"> C - Clean: Same as B above <em>PLUS:</em> Compound Polish Exterior, Clean/Dress Moldings as Needed.    </label>
</div>
</section>
<input type="text" id="total">
```

Working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/3veu206r/

Comment: Just read your question more carefully and updated answer. It now adds up the values instead of simply counting checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

With your code:

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535126(v=vs.85).aspx

```js
window.onload=function(){
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    total  = document.getElementById('payment-total');

 for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
        var new_total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input').value);
      console.log(new_total);
        document.getElementById('input').value=new_total + add
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="extra-features">
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="outside" class="sum" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"> Outside Wash</label>
</div><br/>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="aclean" class="sum" value="39" data-toggle="checkbox"> A - Clean: Wash Vacuum, Windows, Wheels/Tires, Wax</label>
</div><br/>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="bclean" class="sum" value="0" data-toggle="checkbox"> B - Clean: Same as A above <em>PLUS:</em> Shampoo Interior, Clean/Dress Interior Panels, Remove Bugs/Tar.</label>
</div><br/>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="cclean" class="sum" value="109" data-toggle="checkbox"> C - Clean: Same as B above <em>PLUS:</em> Compound Polish Exterior, Clean/Dress Moldings as Needed.    </label>
</div>
</section>
This is the <span> that the javascript is writing to currently:

<span id="payment-total" style="text-decoration:underline;">0</span>
<input id="input" type="text" value="0"/>
```

Comment: This works as well, I ended up using the solution below. Thanks, I upvoted this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do for jQuery

```
$(total).val(parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add);
```

For javascript

```
total.value parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add;
```