# Add up Checkbox Values not working on hidden `div` when shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sum check box values when checked, And display it on another input field.

The bellow given script is working fine. But it's not working on a hidden `div` with `display:none` CSS, When shown with `.show();`.

```js
 function showCheckboxes(){
        $('.checkboxes').show();  
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
    function Calculate() {
      var sum = 0;
      $(".add:checked").each(function(i, n) {sum += parseInt($(n).val());})
      $("#sum").val(sum);
    }
    $(".add").change(Calculate);
    Calculate();
    })
```

```css
.checkboxes {
      display:none;
      margin-top: 20px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onClick="showCheckboxes()"> show Check Boxes </button>

    <div class="checkboxes">
    <div id="selection">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="add" value="5" data-toggle="checkbox"> checkbox 1</label>
    </div><br/>
    <div id="selection">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="add" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"> checkbox 2</label>
    </div><br/>
    <div id="selection">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="add" value="15" data-toggle="checkbox">checkbox 3</label>
    </div>
    
    <input type="text" id="sum">
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a typo here: `$("add").change(Calculate);`, should be `.add`, not `add`.

Comment: @extempl thank you removed typo, but the problem still exists.

Comment: What do you mean it does not work when hidden? When hidden there is no checkbox checked, so sum is 0. It would be empty string value, if function wouldn't executed.

Comment: If you add `checked="true"` to some of the checkboxes - then it will be initially checked and after `Calculate` invocation you'll get the according sum result in input.

Comment: @extempl Not work on hidden div, which i am opening with `.show()` method.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @extempl the result should be same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314872/add-up-checkbox-values-and-write-to-input-field).

Comment: Still not get it. You have hidden checkboxes all of which are not checked. You calculating sum initially (0 as it should be) and on each checkbox `change` which also works well.

Comment: It works exactly as in answer you pointed to. With the exception that your solution is hidden initially with `show` button. So, what is the expected result?

Comment: @extempl when i open this hidden `div` i want to sum all checked check boxes and write it on other input field as I pointed to the link.

Comment: on showing hidden div no checkboxes are checked. If you want them to be checked initially (or on showing hidden div), you should set the checked state explicitly. Showing hidden div just showing that div, no less, no more. If you want the calculation happen on `show`, just add it to the method: ` function showCheckboxes(){
        $('.checkboxes').show();
        Calculate();  
    }`

Comment: @extempl I want to check it after showing it with `.show` and calculate it.

Comment: `function showCheckboxes(){ $('.checkboxes').show(); Calculate(); }`

Comment: @extempl can you make it work with code snippet tool, Because it's not working that's way also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the checkboxes checked automatically when they are shown add the following to your show function:

> ```
> $('.add').trigger('click');
> ```

`.trigger()` method allows you to fire events programmatically (without manual input from user). BTW id cannot be duplicated they must be unique so change the three `<div id='selection'...>` to `<div class='selection'...>`.

```js
$('button').on('click', showC);
$(".add").on('change', calcC);

function showC() {
  $('.checkboxes').show();
  $('.add').trigger('click');
}

function calcC() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.add:checked').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  });
  $("#sum").val(sum);
}
```

```css
.checkboxes {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button> show Check Boxes </button>

<div class="checkboxes">
  <div class="selection">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="add" value="5" data-toggle="checkbox"> checkbox 1</label>
  </div><br/>
  <div class="selection">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="add" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"> checkbox 2</label>
  </div><br/>
  <div class="selection">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="add" value="15" data-toggle="checkbox">checkbox 3</label>
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="sum">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you,Your answer is perfect. please have a look to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fe1w0sy/7/) also why it's not working with this method.

Comment: Got as far as possible https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/v4w98k0g/ Can't do much with the ajax portion. Don't know how it should work or what to expect or if it functions at all with new code.